# Spring Conditional Model Attribute

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple program that allows a user to upload files from a form. In my controller I am setting various model attributes that are created by the success/failure of the upload. All model attributes are displayed in the same view. Lets check out the end of my block of code:

```
                //doin some stuff, etc...
                model.addAttribute("uploadSuccess", "You successfully uploaded " + fileName );
                logger.info("Successfully Uploaded " + fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Load Error: " + e.getMessage());
            model.addAttribute("uploadFailure", fileName + " => " + e.getMessage());
            return "reports"; //returns reports.jsp
        }
    } else {
        logger.error("Could not upload " + fileName + " because the file was epmty");
        model.addAttribute("uploadEmpty", fileName + " because the file was empty.");
        return "reports";
    }
return "reports";
```

As you can see I've got some repetitive code here, so my question is: Is there a simpler way to map a string to an attribute given the condition above (success/failure/other)?

Additionally I need to display said attribute with a single  value in my JSP, rather than what I currently have:

```
<c:out value='${uploadSuccess}' />
<c:out value='${uploadFailure}' />
<c:out value='${uploadEmpty}' />
```

which is just bogus. Desired output would be:

```
<c:out value='${uploadMessage}' />
```

Would declaring all attributes at the beginning of my method with Spring's [`ModelMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) `addAllAttributes(Map<String,?> attributes)` be an appropriate implementation for this particular problem or would it create unnecessary clutter as I'd still have to retrieve them later on in the code? Just bouncing ideas here, cheers.

Comment: Basically you should not validate any data in your @RequestMapping method. All the validation should have been done before. Please see the http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html . If you need a working example just post start of your code as well, I'll adjust it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Babl, I'm not exactly validating any data here, just delegating model attributes. Are you saying this should be abstracted from my `@Controller` as well?